# Sort list with items, order alphabetically

Tags: knockout.js

I want to sort two lists with items and order them alphabetically by firstletter in the name.

I've tried this, without any success:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.storedProceduresInDB1 = ko.observableArray([{
       Name: "A",
       Id: 1
    }, {
       Name: "C",
       Id: 3
    }, {
       Name: "B",
       Id: 4
    }, {
       Name: "D",
       Id: 2
    }]);

    self.storedProceduresInDB2 = ko.observableArray([{
       Name: "C",
       Id: 3
    }, {
       Name: "E",
       Id: 8
    }, {
       Name: "F",
       Id: 7
    }, {
       Name: "B",
       Id: 4
    }]);

    self.sortLists = function () {
       self.storedProceduresInDB1.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name < right.name ? -1 : 1);
       });

       self.storedProceduresInDB2.sort(function (left, right) {
            return left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name < right.name ? -1 : 1);
       });
    };
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/38/)

Comment: Two problems. Enable binding has typos `storedProceduresInDb1` vs `self.storedProceduresInDB1`. Sort function has typos, `left.name` vs `{Name: "A",Id: 1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, the problem is that JavaScript is case sensitive and your code isn't consistent with its casing. The objects in the `storedProceduresInDB1` and `storedProceduresInDB2` have a `Name` key while your sorting code is trying to reference `name` (notice the lowercase N).

Working fiddle with the correct cases: http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/39/

Comment: Ahh, it was so easy.. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it even possible sort a list in the databind? IE. <button data-bind="click: storedProceduresInDB1.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left.Name == right.Name ? 0 : (left.Name < right.Name ? -1 : 1);
            })">Sort</button>   thanks for your time and help. :)

Comment: Yes, you can add pretty much any JavaScript in the data-bind. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zp5K/40/. Though I would recommend highly that you call a method on the view model rather than put a bunch of custom functions in data-bindings.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm appreciate it!